# Using OR logical operator when comparing two columns in R

Tags: r, syntax, logic, logical-operators

I have a large data frame where I'm printing the columns that do not match to another column. I was able to compare column 4 and 9 with this snippet of code:

```
test_no_match <- newtest[which(newtest[,4] != newtest[,9] ),]
```

However, I would like print a data frame where columns 4 and 9 do not match OR if columns 6 and 11 do not match. So it would print if either parameters are true.

I have tried using:

```
testnomatch <- (newtest[which(newtest[, 4] != newtest[, 9] ), ] || newtest[which(newtest[, 6] != newtest[, 11] ), ])
```

But I keep getting errors like

> invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'

Is there a way to compare more than one parameters at the same time? Thank you.

Comment: test_no_match<- newtest[which(newtest[,4] != newtest[,9] ),] | newtest[which(newtest[,6] != newtest[,11] ),]    gets me the error:  Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Comment: You can test multiple parameters at once with `Reduce`.  Please provide a reproducible example with desired result so we can help you further.

Comment: also when I try adding parenthesis separating, I get ‘|’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with ...

```
 testnomatch<- (newtest[which(newtest[,4] != newtest[,9] ),] || newtest[which(newtest[,6] != newtest[,11] ),])
```

Several things.

First, `||` expects a condition of length 1, and is meant to be used in conditional statements like `if(a || b) ....`.

Second, `|` is meant to join two *conditions* of the *same length*. Here you have something different.

So to put the pieces together:

```
 condition1 <- newtest[,4] != newtest[,9]
 condition2 <- newtest[,6] != newtest[,11]
 jointcondition <- condition1 | condition2
 testnomatch <- newtest[which(jointcondition),]
```

Or in one line:

```
 newtest[which((newtest[,4] != newtest[,9]) | (newtest[,6] != newtest[,11])),]
```

This should work but of course, I had no chance to try as you haven't provided a reproducible example :)